# VEC model to VAR model transformation in R

Tags: r, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I need to transform my VEC model (function VECM() from tsDyn package) into VAR model to be able to estimate Granger causalities.

In the first step I need to estimate VEC model. In the second step I run VAR() on the same data (which must be stationary now), just with error correction terms from the VECM as exogenous (as you can see in the code). With the final VAR model I can estimate Granger causalities.

```
vec_mod <- VECM(variables_log[,c(1, 3)], lag = 3, r = 1)
var_mod <- VAR(stac_diff[-1,c(1, 3)], p = 2, exogen = as_data_frame(vec_mod[["model"]][["ECT"]])[-1,])
```

As far as I know, this should be standard VEC to VAR model transformation.
Can somebody confirm me the correctness of this solution or show me some more effective one? Moreover, how can I add a second exogenous variable into VAR()?